# Return array with closest numbers from two different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops

**EDIT**: Here's a rephrase of the question for clarity (apologies for confusion):

**QUESTION :** Given an array limits and an array punct_arr where both are sorted, return an output array of values separation_index where separation_index[i] is the closest value in punct_arr to limits[i]. It follows that separation_index will be of the same size as limits.

---

So, say I have two arrays:

**limits =** [280, 560]

**punct_arr =** [5, 99, 151, 159, 255, 352, 462, 502, 519, 531, 556, 602]

**Expected Outcome:** [255, 556]

The outcome should always be the same length as the limits array.

Here's what I got so far:

```
    for (var limit = 0; limit < limits.length; limit++) {
        for (var punct = 0; punct < punct_arr.length; punct++) {
            if (Math.abs(punct_arr[punct - 1] - limits[limit]) < (Math.abs(punct_arr[punct] - limits[limit])) && (Math.abs(punct_arr[punct] - limits[limit]) < (Math.abs(punct_arr[punct] - limits[limit + 1])))) {
                separation_index.push(punct_arr[punct-1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the arrays are sorted, you can only check the directly minor and major values. Eg: 280 with 255 and 352, 560 with 556 and 602. Then you can keep the n (2 in this case) smaller values.

Comment: That `30` is just an arbitrarily chosen cut-off point, I don't see how that is supposed to be helpful in the first place. (I might even get you _zero_ results, despite there being enough numbers in the input data with a distance _slightly_ larger.) You need to keep track of what element you currently found with the minimum distance so far - and if the next one has an even smaller distance, then that needs to become the new one you "remember" ...

Comment: So confused...Although, What is your expected output?

Comment: I'd wager that what the asker is actually looking for is the following: given an array `limits` and an array `punct_arr` where both are sorted, return an output array of values `separation_index` where `separation_index[i]` is the closest value in `punct_arr` to `limits[i]`. It follows that `separation_index` will be of the same size as `limits`. If this is the actual question, we can take advantage of the sorted nature of both input arrays to come up with a one-pass algorithm using two pointers.

Comment: I think this is still a bit underspecified.  Could you gave a few examples?  Open questions include whether you want the two values closest to *either* of them  (`fn ([5, 15], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 20, 22]) //=> [3, 6]`) or the ones closest to *each* of them ( `fn ([5, 15], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 20, 22]) ==> [6, 20]`)  What do you return if the same value is closest to both of them? (`fn ([5, 15], [10, 25, 35, 45]) //=> ??`), or if all search terms are closer to one?  (`fn ([5, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]) //=> ??`)? And what do you return for equally close values (`fn ([5, 8], [4, 6, 7, 9) //=> ??`)?

Comment: You are correct @wLui155. I have edited my question accordingly and updated the code snippet to my most current "solution". I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a decomposed approach where we start writing at a high-level and define auxiliary helper functions along the way -

```js
function closest (limits, inputs) {
  return limits.map(v => closest1(v, inputs))
}

function closest1 (one, many) {
  return many.reduce((r, v) =>
    delta(r, one) < delta(v, one) ? r : v,
    -Infinity
  )
}

function delta (a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b)
}

const limits = [280, 560]

const inputs = [5, 99, 151, 159, 255, 352, 462, 502, 519, 531, 556, 602]

console.log(closest(limits, inputs))
```

```js
[ 255, 556 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked. But I've been trying to make it so that the output values are always less than or equal to the values of the limits array. Do you think it would be best to implement that in the closest1 function?

Comment: yep! you define precisely what it means for a value to be "closest"

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. I just adjusted a bit your code.

```js
const limits = [280, 560]

const punct_arr = [5, 99, 151, 159, 255, 352, 462, 502, 519, 531, 556, 602]

function closestLimits(limits, arr) {
  const diff = []
  const separation_index = []
  let closest
  for (var limit = 0; limit < limits.length; limit++) {
    diff.length = 0
    for (var punct = 0; punct < arr.length; punct++) {
      var m = Math.abs(arr[punct] - limits[limit]);
      diff.push(m)
      if (m <= Math.min(...diff)) {
        smallest = arr[punct]
      }
    }
    separation_index.push(smallest);
  }
  return separation_index
}
console.log(closestLimits(limits, punct_arr))
```